# how to install xwindows client in my ubuntu?

Tags: xwinwrap

I have established a remote connection with a server from my ubuntu

From the server I'm trying to execute a program that needs Xwindows

So I guess that means that my ubuntu should be able to accept xwindows data and make those graphical windows appear in my ubuntu.

That's why I need to install xwindows am I right??

But when i google about this, I get answers regarding 'xwindows SERVER' installations

I guess installing the server for xwindows wouldn't hurt but is there a way to just install 'client' version of Xwindows?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, xwindows terminology is the reverse of what you expect. Regardless,

```
ssh -Y
```

Will forward your local X11 Display, and then your client    should be able to connect to your local X11 server.